# Want to start on Ejb

Tags: java, ejb

I am currently working as java developer.Now i want to start on EJB. Can anybody suggest me from where i should start. I mean any particular tutorial or site or any book.I am totally new to Ejb.Please suggest.

Thanks,

Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the official Oracle Java EE tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/. Part 4 is about EJBs. For experiments you can use JBoss 7.1.1 and Eclipse Juno which has embedded JBoss support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Should i start directly from part6 ? but i think it's part 4 .

Comment: youre right, definetily 4

Answer (score 0):

I learned EJB 3 by this book: http://www.manning.com/panda/. It's comprehensive and full of examples.